# Then executes before Promise.all finishes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, q

I have this piece of code where I expect that all chargeCreatePromises finishes to execute before orderUpdatePromises executes:

```
return Q.all(chargeCreatePromises)
  .then(function() {
    return Q.all(orderUpdatePromises)
  })
```

The structure of the code is here:

```
function createForThisMonth(order) {
  return Q.all([
    Order.findOne({ _id: order._id }),
    Charge.findOne({ 
      "orders._id": order._id, 
      chargeMonth: moment().format("YYYY-MM")
    })
  ]).spread(function(order, charge) {
    console.log("completed: ", order.completed)

    if (!charge && !order.completed) {
      return createChargeFromOrder(order)
      // returns a promise with Charge.findOrCreate(newCharge);
    }
  })
}

function orderUpdate(order) {
  return Q(Order.findOneAndUpdate({
    { _id: order._id },
    { $set: { completed: true } }
  }))
}

function process(orders) {
  var chargeCreatePromises = [];
  var orderUpdatePromises = [];

  orders.forEach(function(order) {
    if (order.category === 'monthly') {
      chargeCreatePromises.push(createForThisMonth(order))
    }

    orderUpdatePromises.push(orderUpdate(order))
  })

  return Q.allSettled(chargeCreatePromises)
    .then(function() {
      return Q.all(orderUpdatePromises)
    })
}
```

And in different executions, the log is:

```
completed: true
completed: false
completed: false
completed: true
completed: false
```

So, I think that sometimes `then(Q.all(orderUpdatePromises))` is executing before `Q.all(chargeCreatePromises)` finishes.

Could anyone help me understading what is going on here and accomplishes my goal?

Q -> https://github.com/kriskowal/q

node 4

---

EDIT:

I changed `Q.all(chargeCreatePromises)` to `Q.allSettled(chargeCreatePromises)` but the behavior persists.
I updated the code above with this change.

Comment: I'm trying to understand `orderUpdatePromises(orderUpdate(order))`, isn't `orderUpdatePromises` an array?

Comment: Did you intend `orderUpdatePromises.push(orderUpdate(order))`? Note that you don't return anything  in `orderUpdate`. You should add  `return` there...

Comment: Sorry, yes... I'll edit

Comment: also `createForThisMonth()` doesn't return anything => `chargeCreatePromises` is not an array of promises, its an array of `undefined`

Comment: I fixed but same behavior yet

Comment: Hm, if you're in Node, why would you still need Q? Node has had native support for Promises for many, many years now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, this is a legacy code I'm maintaining... I could change for Promise but theoretically this is not a bug of Q...

Comment: I changed `Q.all(chargeCreatePromises)` to `Q.allSettled(chargeCreatePromises)` but the behavior persists.

Comment: Still worth seeing if what happens if you use Promise.all instead. Also, if you're maintaining a legacy project, be aware that Node 10 will be dead as of 2 days from now, so if you're not on Node 12 (or the more recent LTS v14/v16) yet, you may want to consider making "removing Q" part of your uplift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I expect that all `chargeCreatePromises` finishes to execute before `orderUpdatePromises` executes

The execution starts when you call `createForThisMonth(…)` and `orderUpdate(…)` in the loop - all at once. The `Q.all` code only waits for them, but they'll run concurrently and finish in any order.

If you want all `chargeCreatePromises` to finish first, put the calls to `orderUpdate(…)` inside the `.then()` handler:

```
function process(orders) {
  var chargeCreatePromises = orders.filter(function(order) {
    return order.category === 'monthly';
  }).map(createForThisMonth);

  return Q.allSettled(chargeCreatePromises).then(function() {
    var orderUpdatePromises = orders.map(orderUpdate);
    return Q.all(orderUpdatePromises);
  });
}
```